# Use secured database in Java Application

Tags: java, database, security, odbc

I am trying to develop a Java Application to store my login IDs and passwords for various sites.. I want to create a database inside the application itself that will not be accessible by others.. If I use MS-Access or MYSQL .. anyone will be able to alter the database.. I mean that the file should not be visible to anyone as a database and there should not be a way of accessing the database from outside the application.. Please help me with this.

Comment: That's odd kind of requirement and never heard of building such a secure DB. Not sure if say i have mysql running on my machine then how you will access from your's unless you know my ip, credentials and details like that.. Best place would be in memory if you dont want to use file too, but you know the cons of it.

Comment: I didn't say like that. When someone uses my PC he will be able to modify the data in that database right...?? Or they might even copy the database into their machine and the rest will be a misery ... I don't want to let the user know where the database is saved and I don't want to allow him/her to edit it,

Comment: Why not store in your user directory then which wont be accessible to outside world i.e. maintain proper permission on files and directories?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the database to be accessible outside the application, you could run an in-application database like [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) (which comes with the JDK) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/).

Mind you, assuming that you control the machine where the database is running, all databases I know of lets you restrict who can access database files or connect to the database. When you write "anyone will be able to alter the database", what do you mean? See, for instance, the chapter on [Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/security.html) in the MySQL documentation for how to disable access to your database by random users, whether local or remote.

Comment: The database will still be stored locally - and thus accessible to anyone that uses that computer

Comment: HSQLDB lets you run the database purely in-memory (using `mem:`), without storing anything on disk. (Unless others are allowed to inspect and modify memory and swap space of your process.) See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_modes_tables.

Comment: Can you give me an example program of that.. As i am beginner in Java it will be easy for me to understand.. Please do it .. And thank you for your help..

Comment: @SenthilVidhiyakar: Please consult the links in my answer, you should be able to find tutorials and other documentation there.

Comment: I don't think Senthil wants to lose all stored Login IDs when the application is closed which would be the case with an in-memory database.

Comment: What does Java DB mean..?? Do u mean JDBC by that.. I will tell you clearly.. I want to create a Java application that will maintain a database within the application itself.. I will give only the setup files to the user.. for such conditions i should give the database file (whatever type it may be) to the user. But now I want to have the database within the application itself i.e when the user installs the application the database should be automatically generated and will be somewhere within the application... And even if the user finds where the database is he should not be able to edit it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If he never wants data to exist on disk, he's pretty much stuck with in-memory, unless he's storing data remotely (or on  a dongle, or similar). HSQLDB can backup databases to disk (whether in-memory or not), but then you're back to having the database stored locally. (In a slightly more obscure format - a tar.gz file - but still something an attacker could read.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Mind you, even with an in-memory database, data might hit disk due to paging to swap. There are system calls that let you ensure memory is never written to disk, such as mlock(), but I suspect you'd have a hard time integrating that with HSQLDB.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help.. Sorry that I could not articulate my point in a better way.. Anyways thank you for trying to help me...